# Sorting a matrix except its last row

Tags: matrix, sorting

Given

```
M = {{"Utah", 2}, {"Iowa", 1}, {"Maine", 3}, {"Total", 6}}
```

I want to obtain the reverse-sorted result like this:

```
Reverse@SortBy[Most@M, Last]~Join~{Last@M}
```

giving

```
{{"Maine", 3}, {"Utah", 2}, {"Iowa", 1}, {"Total", 6}}
```

Still learning the languange, I kindly ask you to propose a shorter and - probably faster -solution for a country with 10^6 federal states.

Comment: Your code runs in my machine well under 1 sec for 10^6 elements- What is your expectation?

Comment: `M[[Ordering[M[[;; -2, 2]], All, Greater]]]~Join~(Last@M)` should be faster. see [Ordering](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Ordering.html)

Comment: You can use `RotateLeft` instead of `Most` and `Join` but it's not affecting speed. `RotateLeft@Reverse@SortBy[M, Last] &`

Comment: @kguler It's 6 times _slower_ here

Comment: @belisarius - as a novice I just wanted to know, if "I did the right way" - thanks for your quick reply.

Comment: @eldo I'm not saying that there couldn't exist a better approach, but yours isn't bad at all

Comment: @Öskå `c = Transpose[{StringJoin /@ Permutations@Characters["123456789"], Range[9!]}];
M = Join[c, c, c]; Print@Timing[Reverse@SortBy[Most@M, Last]~Join~{Last@M};];Print@Timing[M[[Ordering[M[[;; -2, 2]], All, Greater]]]~Join~(Last@M);]`

Comment: @Oska, @belisarius, a big TIL for me - should stop going for `Ordering` when I see the keywords `Sort`/`SortBy`:)

Comment: @OSka, thanks; forgot `{--}` in the second arg of `Join`:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using belisarius's test setup and a modification of the `Ordering`-based method:

```
c = Transpose[{StringJoin /@ Permutations@Characters["123456789"], Range[9!]}];
M = Join[c, c, c]; 
ClearSystemCache[];
Print@Timing[l1=Reverse@SortBy[Most@M, Last]~Join~{Last@M};];
ClearSystemCache[];
Print@Timing[l2= M[[Ordering[M[[;; -2, 2]], All, Greater]]]~Join~{Last@M};];
ClearSystemCache[];
Print@Timing[l3=Reverse@M[[Ordering[Most[M[[All, 2]]]]]]~Join~{Last@M};];
ClearSystemCache[];
Print@Timing[l4 = Reverse@M[[Ordering[M[[;; -2, 2]]]]]~Join~{Last@M};]
ClearSystemCache[]; 
Print@ Timing[l5 = RotateLeft@Reverse@M[[Ordering[M[[All, 2]]]]];]
l1 == l2 == l3 == l4 == l5

(* {0.406250,Null}
   {3.046875,Null}
   {0.093750,Null}
   {0.078125,Null}
   {0.062500,Null}
   True *)
```

Comment: Much faster (and correct result) now